# Getting individual thumbnal images for different id's(sub geometries)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I need to get thumbnails for sub-parts in the model tree of the forge viewer.(To display the thumbnail along with the sub part label)

I already tried the getThumbnails endpoint but it is only for  the whole object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not supported by default but there are a couple of ways you can get a thumbnail of a specific component in your model:

1. If you're working with AutoCAD or Inventor files, you could use the new [Design Automation APIs](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/overview/) to generate the thumbnail yourself, using the corresponding application's API/scripting. For example, this blog post shows how to generate thumbnails of Inventor models: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/simple-introduction-design-automation-inventor.
2. Alternatively, if you don't mind a more manual approach, you could open your model in the Forge Viewer, hide the components you don't want to see, setup your camera and viewport size, and use the [getScreenshot](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/reference/javascript/viewer3d/#getscreenshot-w-h-cb) method.